# How do I pass latitude and longitude to APIURL?

Tags: swift, currentlocation

i want to pass latitude and longitude variables to "weatherData" function (User's current location). I couldnt this operation. Where am I making a mistake?

```
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var latitude : Double?
    var longitude : Double?

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
        latitude = location.latitude
        longitude = location.longitude
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }

        weatherData()
    }

    func weatherData()  {
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=\(latitude)&lon=\(longitude)&units=metric&appid=APIKEY")
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in...

//other codes
...
..
.
}
}
```

Comment: you could print your url and see weather your passing the variables correctly

Comment: I solved. Thank you for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I would **recommend** reading through [this article](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html) to gain a better understanding of functions and the language.

```
func weatherData(locationVariable: CLLocation)  {

let url = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=\(locationVariable.coordinate.latitude)&lon=\(locationVariable.coordinate.longitude)&units=metric&appid=APIKEY")
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in...

    //other codes
    ...
    ..
    .
}
```

What you want to do is pass through your variable so your end code would be;

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var varLocation = CLLocation()

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let location: CLLocation = manager.location else { return }
    varLocation = location
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    weatherData(locationVariable: varLocation)
}

func weatherData(locationVariable: CLLocation)  {
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=\(locationVariable.coordinate.latitude)&lon=\(locationVariable.coordinate.longitude)&units=metric&appid=APIKEY")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        ...
    }
}
```

We also change your variable to a `CLLocation` to help with general tidiness and type forcing.